# "code ." from git bash vs "open with code" from right click

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh, git-bash

I have a project which includes a git repository in *package.json* and *package-lock.json*.

When I open my project from git bash with command `code .` I can run these commands without trouble,

```
npm update my-git-repository
npm install my-git-repository
```

But when I open my project, by right clicking on a folder and then choosing *"Open with Code"*, and I run the same commands I get these errors,

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git-url-to-my-repository
npm ERR!
npm ERR! git@git: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Both Visual studio code and git are installed under `C:\Program Files`.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** My *package.json* looks like this:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "my-git-repository": "git+ssh://git@git:7999/{repo}/my-git-repository.git", 
  "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  ....
}
```

Comment: `git@git: Permission denied (publickey)` means just what it says: it comes from ssh (not Git) when you have ssh supply a public key to an ssh server that rejects that public key. `git@git` suggests that the server you chose is the one you named `git` and you told that server to let you in as a user named `git`; this procedure (asking to get in as `git`) is normal for github.com for instance, and then the public key you supply acts as both your user name *and* half of your password—it's used to encrypt data that you can then *de*crypt if you possess the private key.

Comment: You'll get `permission denied (publickey)` *from* the server if (a) it doesn't recognize that public key at all (can't find a user for it, or don't allow that kind of public key, or whatever) and/or (b) they gave you a challenge ("OK, prove you're Bob, decrypt this encrypted data") and you failed the challenge. Use `ssh -v` to see which of these is the case. In particular you can try `ssh -Tv git@git -p 7999` and observe the challenge/response sequence. The `git@git` and `-p 7999` are from your URL here.